# Mockito For Testing SharedPreferences Helper Utils

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, mockito, android-testing

I am getting a null pointer exception at `sharedPreferences.edit();` while using Mockito.

Here is my test method:

```
Mockito.when(sharedPreference.edit()).thenReturn(editor);
            Mockito.when(editor.putString(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(editor);

            SharedPrefsUtils.setSharePreferenceString(context, "PREF_ID", "PREF_STRING");
            Assert.assertEquals("PREF_STRING", SharedPrefsUtils.getSharePreferenceString(context, "PREF_ID"));
```

& the shared preferences the setSharePreferenceString looks like:

```
SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(GENERIC_PREFERENCES_TAG,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

        editor.putString(id, value);
        editor.commit();
```

Can anyone tell me what is missing?

Comment: Is the null pointer exception in the Mockito.when() call or in the `setSharePreferenceString()` call?  If it's the latter, is `context` a mock or a real object? ` How is it set up?  It looks to me like your call to `getSharedPreferences()` is returning null.

Comment: BTW, it looks like you're exercising your mocks more than the code under test. You seem to be testing a round trip where the state comes from your mock. The round trip is a good test if you're testing the state change in a real object, but if you're mocking the object that holds the state, it's misleading.   If you have to mock the editor, better to have 2 tests, 1 for setting shared pref and 1 for getting it. That makes it clearer that you're testing the behavior of asking for or changing state rather than the actual storage of the state change.